# When it comes to using derivatives to graph, do I have all of these steps right?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

Perhaps this is a silly question, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer anywhere as to what exactly the steps are for using derivatives to find the shape of a graph (I'm having difficulty even expressing what I mean properly). I've done my best to take information from my textbook and on the internet and create a list of what I think is supposed to be going on.

So here it goes:

Original function:

- used to find $f'(x)$
- produces the y-value for a critical number found using $f'(x)$
- produces the y-value for the inflection point found using $f''(x)$

1st Derivative:

- finds $f''(x)$
- finds critical numbers
- shows what intervals a function is increasing or decreasing on by using the roots of $f'(x)$
- First derivative test: finds a local maximum or minimum

2nd Derivative:

- finds where $f(x)$ is a maximum or minimum by evaluating $f''(x)$ by the roots of $f'(x)$ (which takes place of the first derivative test)
- by using the critical numbers of $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$ can find where the graph is concave up or concave down.
- gives where the inflection points are by finding where $f''(x)=0$, and then evaluating $f(x)$ at these numbers to find the point.

Any help I can get on this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks pretty good, though I would add three more items in your "Original function" section.

- produces the y-intercept of the graph by finding $f(0)$
- produces the x-intercepts of the graph by solving $f(x)=0$
- gives the domain of the graph by finding where $f(x)$ is undefined

That then covers what I teach in my calculus class. There are always more things you could check, such as $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$, and perhaps a few more points of $f(x)$ for special values of $x$ that come to mind by looking at the formula for $f(x)$. (Example: look at $x$ a few multiples of $\pi$ if $f(x)$ includes trigonometric functions.)

Answer (score 1):

To find the shape of graph is also to *plot* it. You have got the basic approach. I repeat the essential steps:

Find as many pairs of points

$$ (x, f(x)) ... \tag {1}$$

as possible. Plot these points on x- and y- axis parallel lines respectively.

This fixes the domain.

Solve $ f'(x) = 0 $ and mark x values with short vertical lines on x-axis.

Calculate corresponding y values for these solved x- values. These points are

$$ (x_{extr},y_{extr}) ... \tag {2} $$

These fix up the range.

Draw a smooth curve through these points.

Increase the number of points ( reduce x-interval) if curve not sufficiently

smooth.

After these basic first steps the role of second derivative is to *confirm*

only,whether the extremum point is maximum or minimum. So it has no *primary*

role in *making* the graph, but helps to verify your plot.